# How many monitors can I attach?

Tags: laptop, display, mini-displayport

What is the maximum number of monitors I can attached with a laptop (Lenovo T440) that comes two usb ports, one VGA port and one mDP (miniDisplayPort)?

Comment: What resolution do you want? 640x480 1920x1080?  For what purpose? Gaming? Documents?  Any 3D work will significantly reduce the number of displays you can attach because performance will be become unbearably slow.

Comment: What video card does your laptop have?  1. The built-in screen 2. attached to VGA and 3. attached to mini-DisplayPort.  If your video card supports display port 1.3 (I think) you might be able to daisy chain a couple monitors on the display port.  USB to VGA or whatever have limited resolutions and generally suck.

Comment: Techically, using USB hubs you can have 127 usb devices.  You could have 127 USB to VGA adapters, but performance would be so slooow you would give up in agony. Instead of Frame Per Second you would have Frames Per Hour.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what graphic card do you have in your laptop. You can check this on linux with command:

```
sudo lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 16
```

You can also check on linux what is maximum amount of outputs and maximum number of simultaneously used monitors:

```
xrandr --listproviders
```

More about that you can read in this thread: [How many displays I can use at the same time?](https://superuser.com/questions/1423137/how-many-displays-i-can-use-at-the-same-time/1423154#1423154)

Remember, that Lenovo T440 can be attached to docking station, which will extend number of outputs.